# ListView selection logic

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, logic

I have a ListView with MultiSelect = false, View = Details and CheckBoxes = True. I'm stepping through it and controlling visibility in an application. I'm currently just using the Else portion of the code below. But it doesn't account for the first Item being selected, it just turns the second item on. And whether or not the item is checked (already visible), and it turns the visibility off. I'm comparing elements associated with the items against elements that are already visible. My app crashes at the currentItem.Checked loop. And doesn't account for combinations (first and checked). How could I code this?

```
        int indexCount = listView1.Items.Count;

        ListViewItem currentItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        int currentIndex = currentItem.Index;

        if (currentItem.Index == 0)
        {
            //listView1.SelectedItems[0] on
        }

        if (currentItem.Index == indexCount)
        {
            //end
        }

        if (currentItem.Checked == true)
        {
            while (currentItem.Checked == true)
            {
                listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
                listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(currentIndex + 1);
            }
            //listView1.SelectedItems[0] on 
        }

        else
        {
            //listView1.SelectedItems[0] off

            listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
            listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(currentIndex + 1);

            //listView1.SelectedItems[0] on                
        }
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're trying to achieve, can you add a bit of detail?

Comment: We need the error message of the cause of the crash.

Comment: I am thinking you are removing the items and since currentItem is a reference to one of the indicies, you are disposing of it when you use the Clear method.  So you currentItem turns to a null value.

Comment: I'm iterating through a ListView turning elements on and off. If the Item is checked, skip it. If it's the first one, turn it on, not the next one. In the linked image, when I hit Next, IRRIGATION would go on. I hit next again, IRRIGATION would go of, it would skip PROCESS WASTE (because it's already visible, checked), and turn Lab Waste on. [link]http://www.topofsteel.com/Images/ListView.png There is no error message. It freezes ctrl-alt-del

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do.

You are basically picking one selected item and placing it in 'currentItem'. If that item is checked as true you are looping through it until? and why?